# How can i have both CrossPlatformInput & Input working at the same time?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

Pretty new to Unity, trying to understand C#, I have been watching some tutorials about getting the Android Joystick working with the game & i am trying to get both on-screen joystick and the normal input working together

So I thought i could type

```
anim.SetFloat("Turn", CrossPlatformInputManager, Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"));
```

or

```
anim.SetFloat("Turn", CrossPlatformInputManager & Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"));
```

or

```
anim.SetFloat("Turn", CrossPlatformInputManager + Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"));
```

Obviously wrong! 
Then i tried having them both in seperate lines

```
void Update()
{
    Turning ();
    Move();
}

void Turning()
{
    anim.SetFloat("Turn", CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis("Horizontal"));
    anim.SetFloat("Turn", Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"));
}

void Move()
{
    anim.SetFloat("Forward", CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis("Vertical"));
    anim.SetFloat("Turn", Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"));
}
```

But unity decides to use the Input first instead of the CrossPlatformInputManager

I know in my head a work around by creating 2 extra floats and a blend tree for the Input its self but that seems stupid creating 2 seperate animations for each input...

The answer is going to be stupidly simple but I started not long ago

Also if someone could explain ' , & + ' for me that would be great too!

Thanks if anyone manages to reply!

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap platform specific controls(or other logic) inside #define ([Ref](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html)).

```
void Turning()
{
    #if UNITY_STANDALONE_WIN || UNITY_EDITOR
                anim.SetFloat("Turn", CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis("Horizontal"));
    #endif
    #if UNITY_ANDROID
                anim.SetFloat("Turn", Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"));

    #endif
            }
```

Comment: I got some errors trying to use this?

Error CS0111: A member 'Player.Turning()' is already defined. Rename this member or use different parameter types
Error CS0111: A member 'Player.Move()' is already defined. Rename this member or use different parameter types

So i tried 

 void Turning()
 {
 #if UNITY_STANDALONE_WIN || UNITY_EDITOR
  anim.SetFloat("Turn", Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"));
 #endif
 #if UNITY_ANDROID
  anim.SetFloat("Turn", CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis("Horizontal"));
 #endif
 }

Was given errors as well, should i be adding anything else to this?

Comment: Modified answer, and did not see that you already tried it. Try to create two separate function like TurnAndroid() and TurnPC(). And then run one of them withing Update wraped in #if define.

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is old, however I think there's few answers about it. I was looking for a solution to the same problem and I am here. I got the expected result by using two types of implementation. For directionals: I used a plus operator; for buttons that triggers an action: I used logic or operator. Examples:

```
// Directionals
anim.SetFloat("Turn", CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis("Horizontal") + Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"));


// Trigger jump
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) || CrossPlatformInputManager.GetButtonDown("Jump")) {
    // do something to jump
}
```